# How do I use Panels to replace a default node page?

Tags: views, nodes, entities, panels

In my Drupal 7.8 installation, I have defined a custom content type "Reviews" which has several fields. Instead of displaying the normal Reviews page for every review, I want to display a panel layout with the fields stuck in different panel regions. I have absolutely no clue how to begin doing this, and I couldn't find any simple instructions.

I have Views, Panels, and CTools modules already installed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found using Views, panels and Ctools a complex and steep learning curve.  Two resources have been very helpful. 1. The video series from Nodeone.se has two video series that can help, "Taming the Beast' (views) and 'Learning Pagemaker'which includes panels. 2. The new book "Drupal's Building Blocks" by Earl and Lynette Miles (Merlinofchaos at drupal.org).

Comment: Thanks! That's a great video series. I've got what I need to know figured out now.